# Sqoop on Hadoop: NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createStarted()

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, sqoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running sqoop on hadoop on Google Cloud DataProc to access postgresql via the Cloud SQL Proxy but I'm  getting a Java dependency error:

```
INFO: First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.shim.HadoopRunClassShim.main(HadoopRunClassShim.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createStarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter$SleepingStopwatch$1.<init>(RateLimiter.java:414)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter$SleepingStopwatch.createFromSystemTimer(RateLimiter.java:413)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.create(RateLimiter.java:127)
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.<init>(CloudSqlInstance.java:73)
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.lambda$createSslSocket$0(CoreSocketFactory.java:221)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.createSslSocket(CoreSocketFactory.java:220)
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect(CoreSocketFactory.java:185)
        at com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:71)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:67)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:904)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:59)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:327)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1872)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1671)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:501)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
        ... 5 more
```

This starts the cluster:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
       --region=${CLUSTER_REGION} \
       --scopes=default,sql-admin \
       --initialization-actions=gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh \
       --properties=hive:hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=gs://$GCS_BUCKET/export \
       --metadata=enable-cloud-sql-hive-metastore=false \
       --metadata=additional-cloud-sql-instances=${PSQL_INSTANCE}=tcp:${PSQL_PORT}
```

And this runs the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export GCS_BUCKET="mybucket"
export CLUSTER_NAME="mycluster"
export CLUSTER_REGION="us-central1"

export SOURCE_DB_NAME="mydb"
export SOURCE_USER="myuser"
export SOURCE_PASSWORD="****"
export SOURCE_HOST="127.0.0.1"
export SOURCE_PORT="5432"

export SQOOP_JAR="gs://$GCS_BUCKET/sqoop-1.4.7.jar"
export AVRO_JAR="gs://$GCS_BUCKET/avro-tools-1.9.1.jar"
export GUAVA_JAR="gs://$GCS_BUCKET/guava-11.0.2.jar"
export PSQL_JAR="gs://$GCS_BUCKET/postgresql-42.2.9.jar"
export PSQL_FACTORY_JAR="gs://$GCS_BUCKET/postgres-socket-factory-1.0.15-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
export INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME="myinstance:connection:name"
export CONNECTION_STRING="jdbc:postgresql:///${SOURCE_DB_NAME}?cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=${SOURCE_USER}&password=${SOURCE_PASSWORD}"

gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop \
       --cluster=$CLUSTER_NAME \
       --class=org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop \
       --jars=$GUAVA_JAR,$SQOOP_JAR,$PSQL_FACTORY_JAR,$AVRO_JAR,$PSQL_JAR \
       --region=$CLUSTER_REGION \
       -- import -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true \
       --connect="${CONNECTION_STRING}" \
       --username=${SOURCE_USER} \
       --password="${SOURCE_PASSWORD}" \
       --target-dir=gs://$GCS_BUCKET/export \
       --table=insight_actions \
       --as-avrodatafile
```

I tried prepending different versions of the `GUAVA_JAR` in the path, thinking that might be it, but can't get rid of the error: `guava-11.0.2.jar`, `guava-16.0.jar`, `guava-18.0.jar`, `guava-23.0.jar`, `guava-28.2-jre.jar`.

`gcloud beta dataflow jobs describe ...` tells me the dataroc image is `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cloud-dataproc/global/images/dataproc-1-3-deb9-20191216-000000-rc01`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve Guava dependency issue while submitting Uber Jar to Google Dataproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911056/how-to-resolve-guava-dependency-issue-while-submitting-uber-jar-to-google-datapr)

Comment: @tix yes, that looks like the same thing, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further research, I see that Hadoop 2.x overrides the classpath, so [the solution is to create an uberjar](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/managing-java-dependencies-apache-spark-applications-cloud-dataproc) and pass that to hadoop.

I also changed to use the specific sqoop jar for hadoop260 instead.

So, I created a `pom.xml` file, ran `maven package` on it to generate the uberjar:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- SEE: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/managing-java-dependencies-apache-spark-applications-cloud-dataproc -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <groupId>org.example.exporter</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-exporter-postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <!-- YOUR_DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqoop</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <classifier>hadoop260</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.sql/postgres-socket-factory -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.avro/avro-tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>repackaged.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>com.google.common.**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```